# NOT IN query is too slow with large number of rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

My SQL query below has been fine until thirdparty_token_airdrops ended up with 200k rows and thirdparty_token_holders had 900k rows. At this scale, what would be the best way to optimise it?

```
select id, owner
from thirdparty_token_holders
where id not in (
    select holder_id
    from thirdparty_token_airdrops
    where status=1
)
and amount > 10000000000
limit 300
```

In terms of indexes, I've created the following:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX holder_id on thirdparty_token_airdrops (id, holder_id);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX owner_address on thirdparty_token_holders (owner, address);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX owner_id on thirdparty_token_holders (owner, id);
```

Comment: The number of rows really doesn't matter, what _really_ matters is your indexes.  Please show us the `EXPLAIN` plan for that query, and all the `INDEX` objects defined for those 2 tables.

Comment: Also, what is the purpose of the `LIMIT 300` clause?

Comment: I'd like to limit the number of results to just 300

Comment: None of those indexes match your query, so no-wonder it's slow. You haven't posted your `CREATE TABLE` statements so I can't be certain, but methinks you'll need "normal" (not `UNIQUE`) indexes on: `CREATE INDEX IX_status ON thirdparty_token_airdrops ( status ) INCLUDE ( holder_id )` and `CREATE INDEX IX_id_owner ON thirdparty_token_holders ( amount, id ) INCLUDE ( owner )` - remember that index column order is important and I assume indexing on `amount` _first_, then `id`, is more specific - reverse the column order if `amount` is less-specific. You'll also need to maintain your `STATISTICS`.

Comment: Oh, and please read through [Markus Winand's amazing web resource all about `INDEX`es in RDBMS](https://use-the-index-luke.com/) **thoroughly** before posting any more updates, just so we know we're both on the same page (pun intended...) and won't waste time with stabs-in-the-dark.

Comment: @Dai will this work on Postgres tables?

Comment: Yes, but you need to be running PostgreSQL 11 or later in order to use the `INCLUDE` syntax. The current version is 14, so if you're on 10 or older then you really need to upgrade anyway...

Comment: I’m using Supabase, not sure what version of Postgres that is under the hood.

Comment: [Supabase uses Postgresql 14](https://github.com/supabase/postgres/), so you're fine.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing the query to this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.owner
FROM thirdparty_token_holders a
LEFT JOIN thirdparty_token_airdrops b
ON a.id = b.holder_id
AND b.status IS NULL
and amount > 10000000000
limit 300
```

Comment: you also might want to check a `not exists` version of the query

Comment: This query is not equivalent to the query in your question.

Comment: @forpas Ah yes, good catch: the `b.status IS NULL` clause should be changed to `( b.status IS NULL OR b.status <> 1 )` - I think?

Comment: @Dai no, they are not equivalent even with these conditions. The query in the question filters out rows of thirdparty_token_holders based on the conditions of the WHERE clause. The query in the answer will return **all** rows of thirdparty_token_holders because this table is LEFT joined to thirdparty_token_airdrops.

Comment: @forpas the issue seems to have returned after 2 hours or so of running. Anything I can do to optimise the query?

Comment: @forpas even with the limit condition?

Comment: If it suddenly slowed-down after seemingly working fine before then I'm guessing your indexes are getting fragmented and/or your statistics objects are stale. Have you been doing a lot of inserts/updates/deletes over the past 2 hours?

Comment: Yea I’m running a query every 15 mins. It worked fine for a while then I started getting timeouts from the database.

Comment: @Dai Btw you mentioned that this query is not equivalent to the one in my question? Why is that? I was under the impression that it was more efficient.

Comment: Not me, ask @forpas

Answer (score -1):

> You can try out with NOT EXISTS. It's better than LEFT jOIN too. Because left join fetches all the possible records for the left table whereas the not exists fetch only matched rows first.

```
SELECT a.id, a.owner
FROM thirdparty_token_holders AS a
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
    SELECT * FROM thirdparty_token_airdrops AS b
    WHERE a.id = b.holder_id
)
AND b.status IS NULL
and a.amount > 10000000000
limit 300
;
```

Comment: Your claim that "`NOT EXISTS` [is] better than `LEFT JOIN` because `LEFT JOIN` fetches all the  records for the left table" is wrong, as is your claim that "the `NOT EXISTS` fetches only matched rows first.": on the contrary, in many cases they are equivalent and result in identical execution plans. [See here for some a counter-examples](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/121034/10044) - remember [that SQL is a _relational calculus_,](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/projects/btr/bioinformaticsschool/slides/gehrke.pdf) **not** a _relational algebra_.